# firestore fetch subcollection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch subcollection of my users document with code below

```swift
    func readData(){
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        self.db.collection("users/\(userId)/saved").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("err")
            }
                if let userId != nil {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                       let docId = document.documentID
                       let cty = document.get("city") as! String
                       let ccode = document.get("code") as! String
                       let countr = document.get("country") as! String
                       print(cty, ccode, countr,docId)
                }
        }
        }
```

but my code doesn't print anything, I don't understand the problem, documents exsist, see picture below

[image]

Comment: That code doesn't fetch a subcollection, it fetches all the documents located at `/users/uid/saved` and reads the fields of each. Is that what you mean or is there a another subcollection not shown in the question? Also what's this `if let uuid = userId {` for? I would also suggest better error checking and handling - this `snapshot!` could be dangerous - do something like this `guard let snap = snapshot else { print("snapshot not found") return }` to protect your code. Lastly, add a break statement within the function and step through the code; let us know which line doesn't look right.

Comment: @Jay document is never read, not printing, not fetching data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using illegal syntax with the `userId` check in the snapshot return but the logic flow is the bigger problem. I would recommend you check if the user is signed in before grabbing the subcollection and checking if there is a viable snapshot instead of checking the state of authentication.

```
func readData() {
    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }
    db.collection("users/\(userId)/saved").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            return
        }
        for doc in snapshot.documents {
            guard let city = doc.get("city") as? String,
                  let code = doc.get("code") as? String,
                  let country = doc.get("country") as? String else {
                      continue // continue document loop
                  }
            let docId = doc.documentID
            print(city, code, country, docId)
        }
    }
}
```